# Periodically load new profile on Ubuntu when running daemon

Tags: configuration, ubuntu

I am running tor as a daemon on a Ubuntu server. I want to periodically and automatically refresh the identity I am using in order to get a new exit node.

The only way I've found to do this is to restart the tor service, but this is not a viable option as it results in downtime for the tor service. Is there a way of doing this with a configuration setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command refreshes the IP without any service downtime:

`killall -HUP tor`

Comment: N.B. there is no guarantee that SIGHUP will result in new circuits (although as it is currently implemented it does) and doesn't do half of what New Identity does.

Comment: What does new identity do that SIGHUP doesn't?